# How to configure OpenDNS for Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, opendns

I have created a wifi adapter & can connect. But I would like to enable [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com) settings. If I enable it for LAN, when [accessing](https://support.opendns.com/entries/25897009-FAQ-Testing-for-Successful-Configuration-of-OpenDNS) through wifi it does not use OpenDNS server. 
I also tried it on the Miniport Adapter settings but no luck.

Can someone tell me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In control panel:

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
```

Right-click the WiFi device & choose properties. In the list of items, select IPv4 and choose Properties.

Under General, select manual and put in the two OpenDNS IP addresses.

Alternatively, if you have control over the Wi-Fi, change the DHCP settings to include OpenDNS instead of the default which will be the ones delivered by your ISP.

Comment: that does not work. I already tried this. After you set DNS server for Wifi Adapter, it cannot be connected.

Comment: Are you sure that your router is not blocking it? It definitely works for me. Do you have any access to the router?

Comment: Julian, its a virtual router. Can you tell me how to configure for that?

Comment: Let me know what software.

Comment: see http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Set-Up-a-Wireless-Hotspot-Windows-7/